# Need blog and shopping cart to contain same login

Tags: php, blogs, shopping-cart

Hello and thank you in advance!

I am setting up a site and it needs both a blog and a shopping cart.  I would prefer to have them both have the same user database and session, so that if they log-in to one they log-in to the other.  I was wondering if anyone has had experience with this and if they found that two specific platforms that worked well together or a single platform that fulfilled both roles well.  The shopping cart doesn't need to be more than basic.

I was thinking of using magento and phpBB or Magento and wordPress but I am impartial to any specific platform.

Thanks again!

Oh and obviously it must use PHP and MySQL ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will the two software on the same domain ?
I have done this using opencart and wordpress and because it was on the same domain we can easily get the session.I just checked the session and accordingly I make user loggin at both the ends.
For eg : my site url was www.abc.com and blog at : www.abc.com/blog

Comment: Yes, they will be the same url.  I have never worked with opencart before but I will give it a look.  Thank you for responding with actual stated platforms, and possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, if you use two different software, you'll have :

- two distinct user tables -- and two distinct databases probably *(which is not a bad idea)*
- two distinct login mecanisms

But you could put some kind of [**Single Sign-on**](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Single_sign-on) mecanism in place, so loging in on one also logs you on the other one.

This is not often done out of the box ; but there are sometimes plugins that will help you implement SSO.

Answer (score 0):

There are often plugins for your forum or the blog to authenticate against a different system, be it LDAP or another database. They generally don't support it out of the box.

See [Share login info between CMSs (Wordpress and phpBB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162290/share-login-info-between-cmss-wordpress-and-phpbb) for an answer to a similar question.